# update table from another table in access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables in access

```
table1 (name,nat) 16000 records
table2 (v_name,id) 189000 records
```

I want to update nat in table1 with id from table2. tried the following

```
UPDATE table1 SET nat = (SELECT table2.ID FROM table2 INNER JOIN table1 ON table2.V_name = table1.Name);
```

got the following

> error: Operation must use an updateable query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `UPDATE .... JOIN` in access

```
UPDATE table1 t1  
INNER JOIN table2 t2
ON t2.V_name = t1.Name
SET t1.nat =  t2.ID
```

Comment: synatx error missing operator in query expression...

Comment: @SamiTarawneh I edit my answer you can try it